# Get Debian Wheezy netinstall to detect wlan

Tags: debian, networking, wifi

I'm attempting to install debian wheezy from the netinstall iso burned to usb. I'm trying to use a Belkin F9L1002v1. First time I attempted installation, I was notified of some missing firmware, so I downloaded the firmware package from Debian's site and put the .deb files in the /firmware folder of the usb. I can now proceed in the installation, but when it attempts to configure the network it only scans eth0, and not wlan0. How do I get Debian  to recognize the adapter?

Last few lines of dmesg:
[image: dmesg]

"Ifconfig -a" returns a command not found error

Comment: Wait two weeks and install Debian jessie instead. :-)

Comment: Haha. But this is sort of an ASAP thing, since I have to have it running by Wednesday.

Comment: Can you not install via eth0 and configure wlan0 later? Linux installers can be a bit finicky about wireless cards.

Comment: The last few lines of `dmesg` would be useful. Also `ifconfig -a`. You can switch to a different console (say, alt-f3) to get those; a picture of the screen (e.g., with a cell phone camera) is fine, as long as its readable.

Comment: Unfortunately eth0 is not an option, it must be the belkin adapter. Unless there is absolutely no other solution.

Comment: I've added a picture of dmesg and reported what occured with ifconfig

Comment: I suspect you're going to need a newer kernel. That firmware was for your wired Ethernet (eth0). That half-cut-off panic seems to be your wifi, is could you get more of that on screen? shift-pageup should scroll. Also make sure to have the firmware-realtek package. See also https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x which gives some firmware that isn't packaged...

Comment: Using the jessie installer to install a snapshot of jessie might be an option.

Comment: Another option, if I'm remembering correctly (sorry, not time to test now) is I think if you run the jessie installer in expert mode, it'll ask you what you want to install—and picking stable/wheezy should be an option. That'll get you a newer kernel in the installer, you'll have to enable wheezy-backports to install it on the actual system as well.

Comment: `/sbin/ifconfig -a`?